# Decrypt SSL connection when having a complete dump

Tags: networking, ssl, tcpdump

how can i debug/decrypt the data of a ssl connection (not https) when having a tcpdump file from the first time connecting until the end? is this possible?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

[Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) can do this if you have the server's private key and if the cipher suite allows it (Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman suites won't work, for example).

Comment: and how can i get the private key? the private key is on a mobile device

Comment: This widely depends on the device. Of course, if you don't have access to that device, it's unlikely you'll be able to get it. You should have legitimate access to the private key to be able to do this.

Comment: it's on an iphone.. so i can't get it unless it's jailbroken, as far as i know